# How to avoid page reload using anchor tag in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, router

I am aware that you should use Link instead of A tag for router link in react. However, I got this error when using link in google-maps-react's InfoWindow:

```
You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>
```

After some digging, I realize this is a known issue in google-maps-react, but nobody has a fix yet.

Well, I could use anchor tag here like

Comment: Can you share your code where you used `<Link>` ?

Comment: You could use [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). please share code snippet  or some fiddle.

Comment: or don't use an anchor tag, call `history.push` or something